# r - chunked::read_csv_chunkwise columns more than needed creates error

Tags: r, csv, chunks

I'm trying to use the "chunked" package to read a big `.csv` file with `read_csv_chunkwise` but there seems to be a problem in my data where the number of columns are more than the number of elements in the first, second or n-th row. This creates an error:

```
>chunked::read_csv_chunkwise(file1, sep = ",", dec = ".", chunk_size = 300000, header = T)

    Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : line 1 did not have 13 elements
```

Can this be fixed somehow ? I heard that other packages like "data.table" have an argument `fill = TRUE` that fixes this problem

Comment: Well, what's actually going on in your data file? Is it malformed? Do you know why the number of columns change? It would be helpful to have some sort of minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know what the problem really is.

Comment: there are empty elements that by default are not turned into NA but an error is returned because the length of the columns (number of columns) and length of elements in the first observations (or any other observation) are not the same. I found this example with "data.table" : read.table( text= "Element1 Element2
Element5 Element6 Element7" , fill = FALSE , header = FALSE )